# Is a python venv portable to other machines with same architecture and OS type?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-packaging, python-venv

I'm building an app based on python3 that uses tkinter and several other packages and I would like to create a an appImage or pyinstaller onefile I can deliver to my remote team members. After spending 4 days trying to get pyinstaller working without success I decided to just create a venv with the required python packages minimal bash scripting and distribute a tar file instead. I thought that would be a quick & straightforward way to go, but even that is proving not to be as easy as I thought it would be. I'm open to suggestions.

I started by creating a folder with a python3 venv (python3 -m venv .) and added all my app files. I activate the venv and use pip to install the python dependencies. I test my app and it works as expected, then I create a tar image of the folder.

When I extract the tar file on a new VM and activate the venv to test, it fails b/c the packages aren't found. Why? the VM is the same OS and machine architecture I used to create the app. I do a pip install of one of the packages that should already be in the venv and sure enough none of them are showing up.

Going back to the dev system I dbl checked if the packages were in the folder I tared up and they were "already satisfied". So what is happening?

Moreover, I discovered that tcl/tk that tkinter relies on isn't installed by default, so that is an external dependency the venv can't resolve, so my choices seem to be narrowing.
I'm just puzzled why the venv didn't preserve the packages my app requires.

Next I'll look into what it will take to create an appImage.

Comment: Virtual environments are not meant to be portable. In the sense that you can not copy, move, or rename the directory containing the virtual environment. Even though in some cases it could work (same Python interpreter implementation and version, operating system, CPU architecture and bitness) , this is not something to be relied on. Said here again: https://discuss.python.org/t/venv-should-check-if-directory-exists-while-creating-a-virtual-environment-106151/28615/10

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, "No, they're not meant to be portable". Sure there are other (more complicated IMHO) ways to package apps, but was hoping venv would be an easy way. As UpAndAdam pointed out, using a venv doesn't save the user from having to set one up on their system, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but not the way you are doing it.  `venv`/`virtualenv` **ARE MADE TO SOLVE THIS (mostly)**. the problem is that you aren't using venv properly.

You are trying to distribute the virtual environment itself along with your code which is not how it works.  You need to create a requirements file with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and include the `requirements.txt` file in your tar along with your project code, that's it. Then the recipient after untarring has to recreate the `venv` on their host or shell and then install the requirements ( `pip install -r requirements.txt`)

As for external dependencies that's a different issue. But a combination of Docker and VENV could solve that. Or you could denote what libraries the user needs to install on their system in a README.

The main key is that you DO NOT put your project files to be distributed into the `venv`/`virtualenv` folder itself.  That folder is just used by pip for managing package installations for your virtual environment.  That folder has to be recreated by the other users manually using the requirements file you produce by freezing your requirements (packages that have been installed into your virtual environment)

Answer (score -2):

A virtual environment (venv) serves as a separate environment for your project and its dependencies. Please ensure that you verify whether your venv is activated or not within the virtual machine (VM). It is important to note that the venv can only be activated through the command prompt.

When it comes to porting the project to a different machine, you can utilize Docker.

Comment: After doing more research on venv I see that will never work. Venvs aren't meant to be portable, not even on the same machine. This comes pretty close tho: https://labs.quansight.org/blog/2020/06/portable-python-env. 

I haven't used docker for GUI apps before, I've heard it's possible but not seen any examples for an interactive docker app that's not console / text based.

Comment: Actually venvs ARE meant to be portable, not directly, but through the use of requirements.txt files they are 100% meant to be portable and reproducible.  That is essential to their whole purpose a reproducible consistent environment within a machine or on different machines. The problem is you are trying to tar the VENV when you should be capturing the requirements with `freeze`